# SPARQL - Count occurrence of a substring in object

Tags: sparql, graphdb

I'm fairly new to Linked-Data and `SPARQL` but I understand the concept and some of the querying as I do have knowledge of SQL. Using some example data from rdfdata.org I managed to setup a GraphDB instance with an [Elvis impersonator repo](http://www.snee.com/rdf/elvisimp.rdf).

Using some basic queries like 
`SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}` and filtering on object values I was able to get some basic data visible in tables. I have experience using regular expressions so I decided to use this with SPARQL to count the occurrence of `Elvis` within the object. However, whatever I do I am not able to get this above one.

This is a problem as I have triples that contain a form of `elvis` more than once:

```
 s: http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/bobjames/
 p: ep:influences
 o: Elvis Elvis Elvis! I also do a Neil Diamond tribute as well, and have 
     been a DJ, MC, and musician for many years.
```

As you can see there are three occurrences of `Elvis` which are only counted as 1.

Here is the SPARQL query used to select the triple and to count the occurrences:

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o (count(regex( ?o ,"[Ee]lvis")) as ?count)
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    filter(regex( ?o ,"([Ee]lvis.){3}")) //only return the triple above
}
GROUP BY ?s ?p ?o
```

How is it possible that these occurrences are not counted? I tried using `str(?o)` but as the object is a string literal to begin with that *should* not matter.

**Expected result:**

le table with 4 columns: `| ?s | ?p | ?o | count |`,
where count should be `"3"^^xsd:integer`

Comment: SPARQL count is used to count the number of matching possible bindings in the RDF data or simply said, the number of matching rows. Indeed there is only one object that matches the REGEX, thus, only one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPARQL count is used to count the number of matching possible bindings in the RDF data or simply said, the number of matching rows. Indeed there is only one object that matches the REGEX, thus, only one row.
Unfortunately, SPARQL doesn't have any concept of *explode* to create multiple rows out of a single row (or better said, I'm not aware of).

As a workaround, I wrote a SPARQL query with REGEX + String hacks. The idea is to

1. replace each occurrence of `Elvis` with some special character that hopefully doesn't occur. I've chosen  `Å`  here for demonstration.
2. delete each other character in the text
3. compute the length of the remaining string

### Query

```sql
PREFIX ep: <http://www.snee.com/ns/ep>
SELECT ?s ?p ?o ?cnt
WHERE {

  ?s ?p ?o.
  filter(regex( str(?o) ,"([Ee]lvis.)")) 
  bind(
    strlen(
        replace(
            replace(str(?o), "([Ee]lvis.)", "Å")
            , "[^Å]", ""
        )
    ) as ?cnt) 
}
```

### Output (sample)

```
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
|                       s                       |                  p                  |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               o                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | cnt  |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/ChuckBaril/   | http://www.snee.com/ns/epinfluences | Elvis, Donny Osmond, Barry Manilow, Pebo Bryson, James Ingram, George Benson, and George Strait                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |    1 |
|  http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/DukeHicks/   |  dc:description                     | Been performing Elvis tribute shows for 10 yrs. Having been in the music business for twenty years Duke knows how to please the audience. Duke started doing his tribute shows after several request from the audience members to do more and more of Elvis' songs and a request for him to do an Elvis Tribute Show. Duke has been asked several times if he is lip-syching to Elvis' songs and the answer is absolutely NO. The sound and stage presence is so close to 'The King' that it has startled many.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |    4 |
|  http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/DukeHicks/   | http://www.snee.com/ns/epcategory   | Elvis Impersonator, Tribute Band                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |    1 |
|  http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/DukeHicks/   | http://www.snee.com/ns/epinfluences | Elvis Presley                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |    1 |
|  http://www.gigmasters.com/elvis/ElvisByDano/ |  dc:description                     | For a great time at your next event, how about ELVIS by Dano? His main goal is to provide a show that reflects the raw energy, passion, and humor that The King once shared with us. Dano, being a huge Elvis fan since his eleventh year, has loved singing along with The Man his entire adult life. He started to impersonate Elvis in public about 1995, and his first long solo performance, with a full set of songs, was at a church social in 2002. Dano was also a seven year member of a classic rock band and often contributed an Elvis act that audiences always truly enjoyed. Starting in February, 2004 he has performed in many solo shows for benefits, auctions, various parties , a Theme Park, as well as much time donated to entertain the elderly. He uses quality audio equipment with great sounding background tracks. Longer travel distances will be considered. Contact Dano today if you want your next party 'all shook up'!!! |    3 |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Comment: And this might not get everything either. Consider if the string were `ElvisElvis`.  Removing the first `Elvis` yields `Elvis`.  So does removing the second Elvis.  What would be distinct is the index of the Elvis in the string, which would produce 0 and 5 (or 1 and 6; I don't remember where indexes start in XSD strings).

Comment: Indeed, you're right - but I never said that my workaround is perfect :D It was just something made in  <5min during the coffee break. From my point of view, this is beyond SPARQL as its primary use-case is graph pattern matching and not computing word count or even IR measures in String literals. By the way, the index is unique but I'm not aware of any `indexOf` function in standard SPARQL. Maybe there are some UDFs in one of the triple stores. Let me know if you found a solution, I'm always happy to learn new ways of using SPARQL. Cheers

Comment: You could get index by replacing "Elvis" and all the text following it in the string with an empty string (e.g., "Welcome Elvis to the building" -> "Welcome "), and the length of the result would provide the index of the replaced occurrence.

Comment: Hm, good idea - but correct me if I'm wrong, this wouldn't work in SPARQL as you'd have to do it iteratively for each occurrence.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I *think* it could be made to work, but without trying it, I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok, I cannot imagine how as a single `REPLACE`command with a single `REGEX` expression would have to do everything and I'm not aware of anything in the regex flavor, even not in Perl where the only way would be to do in-place substitution by e.g. `perl -p -e 's/Elvis/++$i/ge' ` . But if you have some time, let me know once you found a way. If not, I guess it doesn't matter. We got no feedback from the `TO` anyway and I would choose something different then SPARQL, probably Python, Perl or some Bash Foo

Comment: ok,  yeah, part of what I was saying was nonsense.  I was thing of regex as simmering that would produce multiple bindings for the different ways that something could match, like Prolog or something.  That was a mistake. But to count occurrences, you could just replace the target with empty string, then compare the length of the original and the result, and divide it by the length of the target, which would be how many times appeared in the original.  I think the only cases that wouldn't cover is overlapping targets and targets that contain regex special characters.

Comment: I've implemented the last method I'd mentioned (replacing the target with empty string, dividing the difference of the input and the result by the length of the pattern) and added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45280523/1281433).

Comment: Great, I'll upvote indeed. Always happy to see different ways in solving problems! Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by taking the input string (e.g., `"A B A C"`), replacing the occurrences of the target (e.g., `"A"`) with the empty string (`""`) to get an updated string (e.g., `" B  C"`).  Then, compute the difference between the length of the updated string with the input string.  Divide that by the length of the target, and that's how many times the target appears in the input.  For instance:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:>

:a :hasString "I like Elvis." .
:b :hasString "Elvis's name was Elvis." .
:c :hasString "Not mentioned here" .
:d :hasString "daybydaybyday" .
```

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?x ?s ?t ?count where {
  values ?t { "Elvis" "daybyday" }
  ?x :hasString ?s .
  bind(((strlen(?s) - strlen(replace(?s, ?t, ""))) / strlen(?t)) as ?count)
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| x  | s                         | t          | count |
=======================================================
| :a | "I like Elvis."           | "Elvis"    | 1.0   |
| :b | "Elvis's name was Elvis." | "Elvis"    | 2.0   |
| :c | "Not mentioned here"      | "Elvis"    | 0.0   |
| :d | "daybydaybyday"           | "Elvis"    | 0.0   |
| :a | "I like Elvis."           | "daybyday" | 0.0   |
| :b | "Elvis's name was Elvis." | "daybyday" | 0.0   |
| :c | "Not mentioned here"      | "daybyday" | 0.0   |
| :d | "daybydaybyday"           | "daybyday" | 1.0   |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

There are a couple of caveats here.

- The target string must be a "normal" string.  For instance, if it were a genuine regular expression pattern that could expand to text of varying length, this method won't work.
- You need to be aware of how this handles overlapping strings. For instance, if your input text is "daybydaybyday" and the target is "daybyday", are you expecting to count **one** occurrence or **two**?  With this method, you'll just get **one**, because once one occurrence is replaced, the remaining string doesn't have any more.